# Center controls in a panel c#

Tags: c#, .net, center

I have a panel where controls are added dynamically. 
I would like to be able to center all of them on it is panel because for now, they are all glued on the left
[image]

I read that we had to divide the panel and all of them, but I must admit that I didn't understand anything.
Could someone please help me so I can all center?

Thank you.

Comment: which UI framework (forms, wpf, xamarin, other)? What is the curent code? what type is this control, what is a parent control?

Comment: Each control has four properties (including the panel): Left, Top, Width, and Height.  so to center you can take the width of the panel and then set left of each control :control_ left = (panel_width - control_width) / 2.

Answer (score 0):

In the VS Designer try to set the `Anchor` and the `Dock` Property to `None`.
The Control will then be placed in the middle.

EDIT:
Alternativly you can can iterate over those controls and set their `Control.Location.X += (Parent.Width - Control.Width / 2);`

Comment: why did you asume that it's WinForms?